# How to deal with connection and server errors in React/Redux

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, error-handling, architecture

Is there some general patterns how to deal with fetch and post errors in React/Redux application? For example, I have page component containing two container components for different data, and another fails to fetch. Would it be clever in this scenario to dispatch logout action, reset the state and redirect to login page with an error message, or should I only do this if the error cause was actually authentication error?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution to this issue?